# Copy Features (Data Management) and replace the new features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, copy

I am wondering if there is a method to copy and replace features from a source file geodatabase to destination geodatabase that have the same features name.

example : if i have a file named ( A.gdb) and contains a feature named (life)
          i want to copy the feature (life) to a file (B.gdb) but the problem is B.gdb 
          also have the feature (life) already in it, and i need arcmap to replace the
          old feature with the new without giving me that the feature (life ) is already  exists in the destination gdb.

I want to do this in ModelBuilder.

Comment: Does your data have id's and date timestamped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running a model from within ArcMap or ArcCatalog, go to Geoprocessing>Geoprocessing Options and put a check in the box next to **Overwrite the outputs of geoprocessing operations**.  If you are going to export your model and run it as a Python script, add this line to your script.

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is the same as saying:

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True